# Run child processes on cloud foundry node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud-foundry, phantomjs, child-process

Has anyone tried to run child processes on **Cloud Foundry's node.js**?

I have below code running fine locally:

```
var port = (process.env.VMC_APP_PORT || 3000),
    host = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost'),
    http = require('http');


 var childProcess = require('child_process'),
         phantom = require('phantomjs'),
     ls;

 http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    ls = childProcess.exec('phantomjs -h', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
     console.log(error.stack);
     console.log('Error code: '+error.code);
     console.log('Signal received: '+error.signal);
    }
    console.log('Child Process STDOUT: '+stdout);
    console.log('Child Process STDERR: '+stderr);
    });

    ls.on('exit', function (code) {
        console.log('Child process exited with exit code '+code);
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('Working...');
      res.end();
    });

 }).listen(port, host);
```

But `vmc push` on **cloudfoundry.com**, it gave me error in `vmc logs`

```
Reading logs/stdout.log... OK
Child process exited with exit code 127
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: phantomjs: not found

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:536:15)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:634:16)
    at Socket.ChildProcess.spawn.stdin (child_process.js:805:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
    at Socket._destroy.destroyed (net.js:358:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
Error code: 127
Signal received: null
Child Process STDOUT:
Child Process STDERR: /bin/sh: phantomjs: not found

Child process exited with exit code 127
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: phantomjs: not found

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:536:15)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:634:16)
    at Socket.ChildProcess.spawn.stdin (child_process.js:805:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
    at Socket._destroy.destroyed (net.js:358:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
Error code: 127
Signal received: null
Child Process STDOUT:
Child Process STDERR: /bin/sh: phantomjs: not found
```

Then I also added `package.json` file below and still same error:

```
{
  "name" : "mytestchildprocesses",
  "version" : "0.1.0",
  "dependencies" : {
    "phantomjs" : "1.8.1-3",
    "child_process" : "0.x.x",
    "http" : "0.0.0"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, I tried someone else work on putting phantomjs on node.js: https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node. But this option doesn't even work on my local machine (could not call phantomjs.cmd in Windows).

I rather figured out how to do child processes in cloudfoundry.com if you guys can help.

Really appreciate!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Phantom.js requires a binary called "phamtom". I would suggest taking a look at the node-fibers package - https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers. This library doesn't rely on any native binaries and should work fine.

Comment: Maybe I miss something but how does node-fibres help?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have misunderstood. You just want to be able to start a new process in Node.js, right? If so, you can achieve this easily with the node-fibres module.

Comment: I guess I'm slow but is there any example for starting new process with node-fibres? https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers

Comment: There are loads of examples in the README. Fiber(function() { alert('hello'); }).run();

Answer (score 0):

So I just tried your code locally and had issues.

With that package.json npm install gives me an error about child_process not existing in the npm repo. Removing that line enables npm install to complete.

I then get errors about phantomjs not being executable on the path.

If I install phantomjs globally, I see an error about incorrect arguments to phantomjs on the node console when I hit localhost:3000

I'm not surprised that this has issues uploaded to Cloud Foundry as it will definitely require a valid package.json to enable remote installation of the relevant node modules, and if it relies on global installation it will also have issues.

Comment: phantomjs can be installed local or global, but the PATH (for Windows) must point to phantomjs.bat (or .cmd). In that case, the question becomes: how to properly execute a child process when the dependency must be uploaded as well?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 'phantomjs' is listed in your package.json as dependency (not to be confused with the 'phantom' package).

From there on you can get the binary path to the phantom executable by using the following snippet. The phantomjs package ensures that the phantom package is installed on the system. This works on cloud foundry as well.

```
var phantomjs = require('phantomjs')
var binPath = phantomjs.path
ls = childProcess.exec(binPath + ' -h' //.etc etc
```